# Common config in Kubernetes ConfigMap

Tags: kubernetes, configuration, devops, configuration-management

Kubernetes already provides a way to manage configuration with `ConfigMap`.

However, I have a question/problem here.

If I have multiple applications with different needs deployed in Kubernetes, all these deployments might share and access some common config variables. Is it possible for ConfigMap to use a common config variable?

Comment: Hi, Did you find any solution for this question. By what method did you do it?  @edwin

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do that.

- **Kustomize** - Customization of kubernetes YAML configurations (developed as  kubernetes sigs, and had been integrated into `kubectl` command line). But currently it isn't mature enough if compare with `helm` chart

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize

- **Helm chart** - The Kubernetes Package Manager. Its `vaules.yaml` can define the vaule for same configuration files (in your case, they are configmap) with variables.

https://helm.sh/

Comment: Thanks. One more question. Is there a global variable/values in Helm Chart that can be shared across different services/deployments?

Comment: then `kustomize` will be suitable for the request.

Comment: You can still maintain global variables in helm with a global value.yaml file.
During helm command, it can be used like this:
```helm template -f global-value.yaml -f value.yaml .```

Comment: @edwin I have similar use case, curious how you got his working, i used kustomize to extract common properties but im running into the problem that the common props hash is same and its conflicting across different apps.